# Action button in another class?

Tags: ios, ibaction

i have this class to create navigation bar with buttons:

```
NavigationBar.m
+ (void)styleNavBar :(UIView*) view withColor:(UIColor*)color {
// 1. hide the existing nav bar
//[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];

// 2. create a new nav bar and style it
UINavigationBar *newNavBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20.0, CGRectGetWidth(view.bounds), 44.0)];
newNavBar.barTintColor = color;
//newNavBar.shadowImage = nil;


// 3. add a new navigation item w/title to the new nav bar
UINavigationItem *newItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] init];
//newItem.title = @"AmisViewController";

UIBarButtonItem *myAddButton  = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(myAddAction:)];
UIBarButtonItem *myCoolButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cool!" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(myCoolAction:)];

NSArray *myButtonArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:myCoolButton, myAddButton, nil];

newItem.leftBarButtonItems = myButtonArray;

[newNavBar setItems:@[newItem]];
// 4. add the nav bar to the main view
[view addSubview:newNavBar];
}
```

and 2 events :

```
-(IBAction)myAddAction:(id)sender{
NSLog(@"myAddButton");
}
-(IBAction)myCoolAction:(id)sender{
NSLog(@"myCoolButton");
}
```

my problem is when i call my methode styleNavBar in viewcontrollers my application crashed `+[NavigationBar myCoolAction:]: unrecognized selector sent to class`
My question is how i can add methodes myAddAction and myCoolButton ?

Comment: The code looks good to me.  To clarify, those methods exist in that class?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're creating a button inside NavigationBar and NavigationBar doesn't know a method called myCoolAction.

That being said, it's best to style the navigation bar without the buttons and add the buttons later on from a view controller. Now you can set the target to the view controller and add myCoolAction to the view controller.

Another solution is protocol/delegate.

Comment: thanks Rick, i have multiple viewcontrollers or i implementing this navigation bar, i don't want to copy past in viewcontrollers.

Comment: Create a super class (NavigationBarViewController i.e.) and add the buttons with that view controller. Now you can simply inherit from NavigationBarViewController and have the navigation bar in every view controller without additional code.

Comment: can you detail the solution protocol/delegate.

Comment: any other suggestions ?